# Eliminar nodos de un árbol binario de búsqueda

Tags: c++, tree

Se me pide que elimine todos los nodos de un árbol binario de búsqueda, liberando su memoria, y con O(n), siendo n la cantidad de elementos del árbol. Mi problema viene con esta última parte, ¿para llegar a ese orden tendría que usar alguna estructura iterativa (for, while o repeat) no? pero veo más sencillo hacerlo utilizando recursión con el recorrido postOrder.

```
struct nodoABB {
  int dato;
  nodoABB *izq, *der;
};
typedef struct nodoABB * ABB;

void deleteTree(ABB a) {
  if (a!= NULL) {
    deleteTree(a->izq);
    deleteTree(a->der);
    delete a;
  }
}
```

Comment: es correcto tu argumento pero no entiendo cual es el problema? o que esperas...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 el problema es que el tiempo de ejecución del algoritmo debe ser O(n), y no sé si ese algoritmo cumple con eso.

Comment: y como se evalua eso??

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 se llama notación **Big O**. Puedes ahondar sobre el tema en YouTube. De forma simple, se mide con los ciclos. La complejidad de un for es **O(n)**. La de dos for anidados **O(n²)**. La de 3, **O(n³)** y así. Entre paréntesis va una función matemática. Si la graficas te puedes hacer una idea de que el crecimiento de la función `n²` es mayor que el de `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el destructor, deja que el compilador haga su magia:

```
struct nodoABB {
    ~nodoABB() {
        delete izq;
        delete der;
    }

    int dato;
    nodoABB *izq{nullptr}, *der{nullptr};
};
```

El destructor destruirá el árbol recursivamente, si el nodo a borrar está vacío (contiene `nullptr`) la operación `delete` no hará nada.